# Ajax request inside for loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

I set up this for loop to iterate through the array so that I could cycle through each channel to get an object for each value but when I analyze the code I get an error that I should not create functions inside a loop. Is there a more proper way to get this functionality without creating the function inside the loop?

Here is a link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/Na-Ya/pen/EwrOYY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var channels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

for (var i=0; i<channels.length; i++){  

 $.ajax({
method: "get",
url:"https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/" + channels[i],
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function(data){    
// if statement for offline channels 
 if (data.stream === null){

  //sets offlineName to the channel name
  var offlineName = data._links.channel.replace("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/", "").toLowerCase();

  $("#offline").append("<div class='row'>" + "<div class='col m-2'>" + "<h3>" + offlineName + ": Offline" + "</h3>" + "</div>" + "</div>");    
} 
else if (data.stream.channel !== null){

var channelName = data.stream.channel.display_name;
var channelStatus = data.stream.channel.status;
var channelLogo= data.stream.channel.logo;
var channelUrl = data.stream.channel.url;
var channelGame = data.stream.channel.game;  
  $("#online").append("<div class='row'>" + "<div class='col'>" + "<img class='mx-auto' src='" + channelLogo + "' alt='Logo'>" + "<h3>" + channelName + "</h3>" + "<a href='" + channelUrl + "'>" + "<p>" + channelGame + ": " + channelStatus + "</p>" + "</a>" + "</div>" + "</div>");            
}         
 }, //closes out success function   
});  //closes out ajax request
};//closes out for loop   
}); //closes out document ready
```

Comment: by error, i assume you mean warning? If you *need* to create a function inside the loop, do it. if you don't, don't. In your case *not* doing it would mean defining your ajax success handler outside the loop, which wouldn't have any negative consequences.

Comment: Sorry, I mean't I get a warning. I have tried defining the ajax success function outside of the loop but I got stuck and was unable to get objects for each value of the array.

Comment: That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, function in loop can be avoided by writing it, as a *named* function, outside the loop and using the name to specify the function as the success handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var channels = ...;
    function successHandler(data) {
        ...
    }
    for (var i=0; i<channels.length; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            'method': 'get',
            'url': 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/' + channels[i],
            'dataType': 'jsonp',
            'success': successHandler
        });
    }
});
```

That should anwer the question.

In addition, as written the sussess handler lacks an unconditional `else`, therefore if `data.stream === null` and `data.stream.channel === null`, no HTML will be built/displayed. That may never happen but you should program defensively - always assume the worst.

Consider instead :

```
if (data.stream && data.stream.channel) {
    // build HTML for the Channel 
} else {
    // build HTML for offlineName 
}
```